# Image isn't been shown despite a correct path

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, path, filepath

I'm creating images dynamically, and assigning path from sql server, but images on the server are not being displayed.

The pic_list contains paths for all images as follows:

```
~/Member_Data/039658893/images/one.jpg
```

**my code:**

```
for (int j=0; j<pic_num; j++)
            {

                TableCell c1 = new TableCell();


                    ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
                    img.ID = temp.ToString();
                    img.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath(pic_list[temp]);
                    img.CssClass = "img_bg" ;
                    img.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(delete_pic);

                    c1.Controls.Add(img);


                r1.Controls.Add(c1);
```

**images are not beig shown and when I inspect them in chrome I get this path:**

[image]

**and when I click the hyperlink I get to this page:**

[image]

I checked and the image file exist on the server.

How should I write the path?

Answer (score 1):

That `C:\inetpub\wwwRoot\...\efi5.jpeg` path is full file system path, not path that should be used on web server. Those paths technically are correct but not in the context you want (web server). You need to remove the path of the web server root directory which is `C:\inetpub\wwwRoot\` from all your links, and just leave the `igroup20\test2\Member_data\039658893\images\efi5.jpg`. Then you will have a path which is relative to the web server root.

Keep in mind that they are relative to the web server root, and that you need to whatch from which directory they are called. So i would suggest you build absolute links such as:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/igroup20/test2/Member_data/039658893/images/efi5.jpg">
```

instead of just

```
<a href="igroup20/test2/Member_data/039658893/images/efi5.jpg">
```

Comment: how would I do that? my path in the sql server is in this format: ~/Member_data/039658893/images/efi5.jpg and it gives me an href to: "http://proj.ruppin.ac.il/igroup20/test2/~/Member_data/039658893/images/efi5.jpg

Comment: First you don't need Server.MapPath function, just use the path you have. If all your images are located in `igroup20\test2\ ` directory and the files are called from there, you just need to remove the leading `~/` from the path. That way you will get `Member_data/039658893/images/efi5.jpg` and when you make a HTML link with that path it should open `http://proj.ruppin.ac.il/igroup20/test2/Member_data/039658893/images/efi5.jpg` which works.

Comment: I did it and it works, but when I upload new files and try to display them it throws me to a page with   "HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for this resource on the Web server.

Comment: I don't think that is a related error. Can you give us a path of that URL on which you get that error? If it's a path to directory in which the files are it is a normal error to get.

Comment: that's the path in the browser: "http://proj.ruppin.ac.il/igroup20/test2/Member_Data/039658893/images/pic3.jpg" so it's weird

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath` gives you physical path to the file on the server.

You need path to an image as browser would see it. Something like `"/Member_Data/039658893/images/one.jpg"` is what you are looking for.